# Why the analyzer propose this move?

Tags: analysis

[image]

My move was Kxc3. The move was labeled as a blunder. Why?

Comment: It is hard to tell what the actual position is at the time you played Kxc3

Comment: If the engine considers your move a blunder and your opponent fails to exploit it (as was the case here), your opponent's move is a blunder too, so you can figure out why your move was a blunder from the comments attached to your opponent's move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, Kxc3 loses a piece or the exchange after Rc8.

```
[fen "1n3rk1/5pp1/4p2p/8/q1N1QP2/Pnp4P/1PK2PP1/3R1R2 w - - 0 0"]

1. Kxc3 Rc8 2. Rd6 {or any move} Na5 3. Rd4 Qb3+ 4. Kd2 Nxc4+
```